# List index out of range gives me

Tags: python, list, index-error

I am trying to create matrix in python But it gives me IndexError.

```
from random import random, randint
my_list = []
for a in range(4):
    for b in range(4):
        my_list[a][b] = randint(10,99)
        print(mylist[a][b])

    print()
```

Comment: You are getting this error because you have initialized list empty and in for loop you are trying to access elements of a empty list. Try to append values instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 1):

By using `my_list[a][b]`, you're trying to access indexes that haven't been created yet.

Try this instead:

```
from random import randint

my_list = []
for a in range(4):
    row = []
    for b in range(4):
        row.append(randint(10, 99))
    my_list.append(row)

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension,

```
from random import randint

my_list = [[randint(10,99) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
```